# How do I diagnose a failing AWS Database Migration Service task?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I just set up an AWS DMS Task to copy an RDS Postgres database from one AWS account to another.  I've created and tested both endpoints and I know the task can connect to each endpoint.  However, when I run the task, it changes from `Starting` to `Running` to `Failed` and leaves the following message:

```
Last Error Task error notification received from subtask 0, thread 0 
[reptask/replicationtask.c:2673] [1020482] Stop Reason FATAL_ERROR Error Level FATAL
```

Here is a screenshot of the task:

[image]

I see that there is a link to CloudWatch but when I click it, the log group doesn't exist and I see this message:

[image]

How can I diagnose this task?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if you have already resolved this or not but I managed to fixed this.

1. Open the IAM console
2. Choose **Role** on the left hand panel
3. Choose **Create Role**
4. Choose **AWS Service** -> **DMS**
5. Press **Next : Permission**
6. Search for **AmazonDMSCloudWatchLogsRole** in the search box
7. Press **Next : Tag**
8. Press Next to proceed to the Review section
9. Put in the Role Name, Role Description as necessary
10. Choose **Create Role**

After you finished the above step, you can go and restart your failed DMS task and can view the log now.
reference : https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/dms-cloudwatch-logs-not-appearing/

Comment: you must need to create role `dms-cloudwatch-logs-role`. in my case there was issue on role's name.